# GWT: How to migrate to gwt 2.7.0 from gwt 2.6.0

Tags: gwt, migration

I am using GWT 2.6.0 right now and I would like to change my SDK version to 2.7.0. Eclipse does not have 2.7.0 now, so I downloaded the newest SDK manually and changed the SDK setting in project property. But I cannot make it work, the compiler complains:

```
 [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.translateException(JVisitor.java:121)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:296)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:128)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:67)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:128)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContext.traverse(JModVisitor.java:95)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemove(JModVisitor.java:351)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:92)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:149)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:600)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:569)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:1505)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:870)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.unifyJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1305)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.constructJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1038)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:954)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:303)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:38)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:286)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:206)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:158)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl.setUserData(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/w3c/dom/UserDataHandler;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.W3cDocumentBuilder.startElement(W3cDocumentBuilder.java:127)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.W3cDomHelper.documentFor(W3cDomHelper.java:74)
    at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator.getW3cDoc(UiBinderGenerator.java:204)
    at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator.generateOnce(UiBinderGenerator.java:179)
    at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator.generate(UiBinderGenerator.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:760)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:160)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createStaticRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:485)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:443)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:576)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:306)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
    ... 40 more
      [ERROR] at CompInfoEditor.java(21): GWT.create(CompInfoEditor$MyUiBinder.class)
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
      [ERROR] at CompInfoEditor.java(21): (CompInfoEditor$MyUiBinder) GWT.create(CompInfoEditor$MyUiBinder.class)
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation
      [ERROR] at CompInfoEditor.java(21): static CompInfoEditor$MyUiBinder uiBinder = (CompInfoEditor$MyUiBinder) GWT.create(CompInfoEditor$MyUiBinder.class)
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement
      [ERROR] at CompInfoEditor.java(18): {
  ContentPanel.$clinit();
  static CompInfoEditor$MyUiBinder uiBinder = (CompInfoEditor$MyUiBinder) GWT.create(CompInfoEditor$MyUiBinder.class);
}
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock
      [ERROR] at CompInfoEditor.java(18): {
  ContentPanel.$clinit();
  static CompInfoEditor$MyUiBinder uiBinder = (CompInfoEditor$MyUiBinder) GWT.create(CompInfoEditor$MyUiBinder.class);
}
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody
      [ERROR] at CompInfoEditor.java(18): private static final void $clinit();

         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this issue is fixed. It's caused by the build order.

In addition to GWT, I am using GXT, which seems like "shadowing" com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderWriter class.

The solution is that move GWT SDK before gxt.jar in Order and Export setting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641849/gwt-2-5-0-compiler-exception) and [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401779/com-google-gwt-dev-jjs-internalcompilerexception-unexpected-error-during-visit).

If so, just delete all files in your project's **gwt-unitCache** folder and you should be fine.

Comment: Hmmm, it might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312112/problems-with-my-apache-cxf-client, then. You might have an obsolete xerces lib somewhere in your build path.